# How to always call a class method, forcefully, on return in python

Tags: python

I have a `ReportEntry` class

```
class ReportEntry(object):
  def __init__(self):
      # Many attributes defined here

  ... # Lot many setattr/getattr here
  def validate(self):
      # Lot of validation code in here
      return self
```

Multiple other classes maintain `has-a` relation with `ReportEntry` class

```
class A(object):
  def test1(self):
    t1 = ReportEntry()
    # Assign the attribute values to t1
    return t1.validate()

  def test2(self):
    t2 = ReportEntry()
    # Assign the attribute values to t2
    return t2.validate()
```

And there are multiple such classes as A.

I need to enforce each `ReportEntry` class instance to call `validate()` on `return` or maybe just before `return`.

Basically, no instance of `ReportEntry` should escape validation since the final report generation will fail if something is missing.

How may I achieve that ?

Comment: Why not have a `isValidated` boolean flag, check before the final report generation, and raise an error if the flag was unset?

Comment: I thought of this approach too. But again, it's like, `if someone forgets to call validate`. I was thinking along the line `you need not explicitly call validate, that will be done automatically`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach that I could think of is to define `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods where `validate` is called upon `__exit__` in `ReportEntry`

```
class ReportEntry(object):
  def __enter__(self):
    return self
  def __init__(self):
  # Many attributes defined here
  ... # Lot many setattr/getattr here
  def validate(self):
    # Lot of validation code in here
    return self
  def __exit__(self, a,b,c):
    self.validate()
    return True

# And then use it as
with ReportEntry() as report:
    ...
```

But again, this will be enforced only when used `with ReportEntry() as report:`

Comment: It still doesn't solve the problem that I thought you wanted, which was for `validate` to run autonomous of whether it was explicitly called in each `testx` function, if the functions are created in client space, it would make sense to have the function called in some sort of inheritance pattern.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't solve the auto enforced feature which I wish if the class in not instantiated with a `with`

Comment: Hmm, does `validate` need to be called after the body of `test1`?

Comment: Yes, each of such tests, spread across different classes, whenever instantiate `ReportEntry`, populate few of the attributes from that instance. And towards the end, the `validate()` should be called automatically, even if the method forgets to call it explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a class decorator:

```
import inspect

def validate_entries(cls):
    def validator(fnc):  # this is a function decorator ...
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            rval = fnc(*args, **kwargs)
            if isinstance(rval, ReportEntry):
                # print('validating')
                return rval.validate()
            return rval
        return wrapper
    for name, f in inspect.getmembers(cls, predicate=inspect.isfunction):
        setattr(cls, name, validator(f))  # .. that we apply to all functions
    return cls
```

Now you can define all `A`-like classes:

```
@validate_entries
class A(object):
    # ...
```

This will validate any `ReportEntry` that is returned by any of `A`'s methods.

Comment: This approach will put the onus of validating the entries on the classes using `ReportEntry`, right ? If they don't use the decorator `validate_entries`, nothing is stopping them to use invalid report, right ?

Comment: That is correct, as it is for your inital approach. The improvement is that you only have to wirte one line per class not one for every method. That being said, it feels that the validation should go where it is actually needed, in the final report generation. But a report entry object itself cannot know about how it is being used, whether it is assigned to a variable or put in a list or returned from a function.

Comment: Actually the thought is, that wherever `ReportEntry` is being instantiated, right there after all the assignments, before it returns, it should be `validated` automatically. So, any exception raised in the validation can report which `class` and which `method` of that class is having issue. All the `ReportEntry` objects are collected in a list and final report generation consumes that. If validation goes there, then this information may be lost.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways I can think about to go about this. I cannot say more without knowing more implementation details:

1. Decorate your methods: Where every return instance is run through the decorator function. You may want to put this as a stand-alone function or part of a class depending on your specific use case.

   ```
   def validate(func):
       return func().validate()

   class A(object):
       @validate
       def test1(self):
           t1 = ReportEntry()
           # Assign the attribute values to t1
           return t1
       @validate
       def test2(self):
           t2 = ReportEntry()
           # Assign the attribute values to t2
           return t2
   ```
2. Updating the __setattr__ and decorate your class:

   ```
   def always_validate(cls):
       # save the old set attribute method
       old_setattr = getattr(cls, '__setattr__', None)
       def __setattr__(self, name, value):
           # set the attribute
           validate(name, value)
           old_setattr(self, name, value)

       cls.__setattr__ = __setattr__

       return cls
   ```

and then you could decorate your ReportEntry:

```
@alway_validate
class ReportEntry(object):
    ...
```

Comment: The first approach would give `Class A` to get away without validation, right ? And with the second one, each attribute `setattr` is validating it right at the time of assignment, right ?

Comment: With the first approach, the validation will only happen for the methods you decorate. If you choose not to validate a method, perhaps a method that is not a testx, then you can simply not decorate that method.

Comment: Yes. But the one who uses the `ReportEntry` may have an excuse `Oh !! I forgot :P` Since many new people will be using this class, project wide, I was looking at some way to enforce it

Comment: in that case, approach 1 will do. No ReportEntry attribute can be set without validation

Comment: Oh ok, so the `__setattr__` in the `ReportEntry` class do have some validations. But the final report generation needs a minimum set of attributes to be set. That is what my `validate()` is checking, that the minimum number of attributes required to generate final report are `not missing/not None` from instance

Comment: In that case the best solution would be to check eveything that is just about to be generated on the final report. I am assuming you have another class that consumes these small reports. There HAS to be a trigger at some point to start validating. As long as a method in A is running there is no way to know when to validate. Only Class A can do it before return. But it seems you don't favor that. Then I would suggest putting that validation on the final Class. Will that work?

Comment: Check my last comment in the other answer proposed below. It's not that I don't `favor that`, it's just that someone using the class may `forget/get away` without validation and final report generation will fail

Comment: how do you generate the final report?

Comment: The final report generation method iterates over ultiple `ReportEntry` instances, populated from different classes, appended in a list. Attributes from each instance, combined with string from a YAML file, constitute the final report. Hence a minimal set of attributes, from each instance, is required which is what `validate()` is making sure

Comment: Perfect, why not call validate when iterating over the list of final reports then? That seems to be the best fool proof spot